# How many HSDir nodes are there?

Tags: onion-services

[This answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6746/7222) references the number of hidden service directories. How can I find out how many HSDir nodes there are?

Answer (score 1):

https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/ lists the number of V2Dir nodes (currently 4174).

Unless I'm reading the wrong statistic, which is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the official API called "onionoo".
All you need is to count all of the relays.
Here is the link: https://onionoo.torproject.org/summary?flag=v2dir
[image: Just a pic]